# Angularjs Dom Manipilation in a Table

Tags: angularjs, dom

i have a table where i can turn pages, you can choose a color for a user and that color is shown in the circle, but when i turn one page, the color is gone!

I read about dom manipluation in directives, but that still didnt solve my problem:

1. the tutorials mostly show one with a click funktion, and i dont to click the circle
2. they also werent "permanent"

maybe i did something wrong? please can someone help or give me a hint?

```
i made also a plnkr :
```

[Here's the link](http://plnkr.co/edit/NEoyFKP217kS94J7fchx?p=preview)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save chosen color to currect user object. Maybe like this:

```
$scope.showColorPicker = function(user) { 
    data = $scope.colors;
    dlg = $dialogs.create('/dialogs/pickColor.html','pickColorCtrl',$scope.colors,{},{key:false ,back:'static'});

    dlg.result.then(function(data) {
        var colnr = data;
        var user_circle = angular.element(document.getElementById('color_' + user.id));
        user_circle.context.style.backgroundColor = $scope.colors[colnr-1].color;
        user.color = $scope.colors[colnr-1];
    });
};
```

HTML for color circle:

```
<span class="smallcircle" ng-bind="color_{{user.id}}" id="color_{{user.id}}" name="color_{{user.id}}" style="background-color: {{user.color.color || 'lightgray'}};"></span>
```

Make sure you pass user object to `showColorPicker` function:

```
<a href="" ng-click="showColorPicker(user)">Change Color</a>
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/em0ZUHjbXUNa7MYgpC5f?p=info

Comment: wow, that makes so much sense,and i got stuck there... thank you!!

Comment: hey, i have an other  question, when i start that in internet explorer, the colors in the dialog that open, are grey! debugger says background-color:{{col.color};(one } is missing!) how do i fix that? i tried it with \}\} but it still dont work, do you have any ideas??